# Python not reading extend argument in colorbar?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code plotting a contour on a basemap named m:

```
v = np.linspace(0, 900, 16, endpoint=True)
cf = m.contourf(x,y,ozone,v, cmap = colormap)
cb = plt.colorbar(cf, orientation= 'horizontal', extend = 'both')
```

It works, except that Python is *not* reading the extend argument of the colorbar. I put an invalid  keyword for extend (e.g. extend = 'jfs') to see if it was even evaluating, and it did not throw an error. It is, however, reading the orientation argument. Is there a bug here I am not seeing?

Comment: For contours, the `extend` argument needs to go into `contour`, not the colorbar, because the colorbar wouldn't know what to extend, if the contour levels did not already carry that information. See the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_hatching.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mathplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html):

> For the out-of-range values to display on the colorbar, we have to use the extend keyword argument. To use extend, you must specify two extra boundaries. Finally spacing argument ensures that intervals are shown on colorbar proportionally.

```
bounds = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    cax=ax,
    boundaries=[0] + bounds + [13],
    extend='both',
    ticks=bounds,
    spacing='proportional',
    orientation='horizontal',
    label='Discrete intervals, some other units',
)
```

So you need to add boundaries to extend the colorbar.